# Unusual results when sorting an array of objects by a property each object has

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of objects by a property `rank` which each object has. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript) seems to be the accepted way of doing it. However, it does not seem to be working correctly.

```
var waypoints = ig.game.getEntitiesByType(EntityWaypoint); // returns array of objects
// This line tells sort to order by Array[i].rank
waypoints.sort(function(a,b) {return (a.rank < b.rank) ? -1 : (a.rank > b.rank) ? 1 : 0;});
waypoints.sort();
for( var i=0; i<waypoints.length; i++ ) {
    console.log(waypoints[i].rank);
}
```

Console ends up looking like this:

```
4
1
2
3
5
6
7
```

I've also tried the following variation which results in the same thing.

```
waypoints.sort(function(a,b) {return (parseInt(a.rank) < parseInt(b.rank)) ? -1 : (parseInt(a.rank) > parseInt(b.rank)) ? 1 : 0;});
```

Why isn't this properly sorting an array of objects by the `rank` property of each object?

Comment: You should be able to do just `return a.rank - b.rank;`, the [subtraction](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2) will force `rank` to be converted to a number (if it can be).

Comment: `waypoints.sort(function(a,b) {return a.rank - b.rank;});` seems to work, but I have no idea why. Does this method only work for numbers or would it work for words?

Comment: For some version of "work", yes, but probably not how you expect. The comment above has a link to the internal [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) algorithm, and the special treatment of [strings](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1). Essentially if the string converts to a number literal (e.g. "12" -> `12`), then that happens. Other strings (e.g. "foo" -> `NaN`) not so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There is nothing wrong with your custom sort](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/6vsrE/). Your first piece of code calls `waypoints.sort()` twice. The second sort is mucking with the ordering; remove it.

Comment: Worked great, thank you! Seems strange though that sorting a sorted array could unsort it...

Comment: Because the first sort is sorting numbers, the second is sorting objects. The algorithm is in [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11).